# Polycrylic getting sticky and peeling/wearing off

Tags: wood, polyurethane, desk, finish

I coated a bare wood acacia table for a computer desk with Minwax polycrylic about 4 months ago and made sure it was dried the recommended 24 hours before regular use. 4 months later, I noticed the edge where I rest my arms was getting sticky and peeling off. I thought it was just grime from my hands or something, then I realized it was a rubbery substance. I scraped it a bit and I could see the bare wood beneath. It was all sticky and rubbing off, and becoming a lint trap. Is this normal that Minwax polycrylic does not tolerate regular human body contact? I would not expect regular body temperature to be "high heat". Or did I do something wrong? Is the deterioration caused by heat or oil? Also, would the stickyness disappear and the finish solidify again if I stop using it?

I am intending to sand off the rubbery section and re-finishing the area. Is it okay to put the new layers of finish over some thin layer of residue? Will it bind? Also buying a desk mat to protect the surface.

Comment: You might have better luck at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Although Minwax looks nice there all in 1 methods don’t hold up as well as other brands of poly, I stick to old school oil based poly , they say the latex is as good but I think it is close but not quite there when you want rock hard super clear finish.  For home users that want quick and easy try varathane triple thick not as many coats required and easy clean up.